# soapUI: Error does not close tag

Tags: web-services, soapui

I'm trying to use soapUI 4.5.2 for the first time. I've created simple .NET ASPX web service and copied the following address into the soapUI:

```
http://localhost:52086/WebService1.asmx
```

But, the following error came up:

```
Error loading [http://localhost:52086/WebService1.asmx]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: does not close tag
```

I've disabled proxy option in soapUI preferences.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Watch for **?wsdl**.

You should use it like this:

```
http://localhost:52086/WebService1.asmx?wsdl
```

Answer (score 47):

I had the same problem with *SoapUI* 5.0.0 on *Linux* Mint.
In my case the wsdl url was correct and it could be reached via any browser.(**you might need to add '?wsdl' to the end of url**).

```
http://localhost:52086/WebService1.asmx?wsdl
```

In my case, I had configured my firefox to use a proxy server and *Soupui* was trying to load **proxy** setting from my **Mozilla Firefox** which caused SoapUI to be unable to resolve import XSD of WSDL which resides on my local Network.
After setting **proxy** to **None** in Soapui the problem has been resolved too.

> File->Preferences->Proxy Settings->None

Answer (score 5):

You have to Instruct that weather it is server uri or not so there is way to way to wrote this like this

example

```
http://192.XXX.X.XXX/Service/Servicename.asmx?wsdl
```

try this.

Answer (score 5):

FIX STEPS:
1. On SOAP UI Tool. Click File>Options, then click Proxy Settings
2. Change automatic to manual and write localhost in Exclude
3. Retry importing WSDL.

Comment: thank you, that's what I needed. I had "?wsdl" at the end, so this solved my problem

Comment: I fixed my issue in the java web service as you suggested, thank you

Answer (score 1):

can't find your URL for the soap,
I have the same problem with you,
and I enter the URL into the chrome's address bar ,then I find the 404 not found!
so , I change my URL and tried again, It's works.

So, My suggest is: change your URL and try again!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a wcf service, turning off proxy setting on soap ui worked for me.
Do not forget the ?wsdl part on your url.