# org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error

Tags: web-services, soapui

I have installed SOAP UI 5.3 in my university system. While loading web services to a new project the following error is appearing:

> org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error

I have done all possible solutions given on the Internet.

I was getting two errors:

> org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException:org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: does not close tag.

I resolved it by *[soapUI: Error does not close tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270500/soapui-error-does-not-close-tag)*.

But I am unable to resolve below one.

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Resolved-error-does-not-close-tag/td-p/29309, set none in proxy setting in my system.

The error descriptions are misleading. Please suggest if anyone can help me.

I have tried with the following web services:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit and used other web services as well, but I am unable to load in the SOAPUI project.

Comment: You need to contact the wsdl provider.

Comment: Its not wsdl problem , its is network related issue, what i have mentioned in problem. WSDL is completely fine

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem solution was really simple, you just need to add ?wsdl in web service url.
http://localhost/service?wsdl

Seems like Error was misleading